construction of a basic hypothesis test for a coin toss
I have a coin and I know already that it is either a fair coin with $p=\frac{1}{2}$ or an unfair coin with $\frac{3}{4}$ and now I want to test if it is a fair coin or not with significance $\alpha = 0.05$ and test power $\beta(\theta)=0.9$
Here is a summary what I did so far:
I chose a one sided hypothesis test, denote it as $T$, since there are only two parameters in question with the following idea:
I toss it $n$ times and get $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli-Variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$, now if
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i > C$ for critical value $C>0$ then $T=1$ (reject the null) and $T=0$ (accept the null) otherwise. The critical set $K$ on which I reject the null contains then all integers from $c+1,\dots,$
Now, I want to choose $C$ such that the first restriction of the significance level is satisfied using the central limit theorem:
(I do not want to make the post too long but just say if you would like the calculation in detail and I will provide it ofc):
$\mathbb{P_{\frac{1}{2}}}(K) \leq 0.05 \implies C = \left\lceil \frac{ \displaystyle 1,645 \cdot \sqrt{n} + n}{\displaystyle2} - 1  \right\rceil $
now, I want to satisfy the second restriction of the test power: how to do this?
More specifically:
using again, the central limit theorem, I need:
$\mathbb{P}_{\frac{3}{4}}(K) \approx 1 - \Phi \bigl(\frac{\displaystyle C+1-\frac{3n}{4}}{\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{3n}{16}}}\bigr) \geq 0.9$
So I need
$\Phi \bigl(\frac{\displaystyle C+1-\frac{3n}{4}}{\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{3n}{16}}}\bigr) \leq 0.1 $
taking the inverse of the normal cumulative distribution function I observe that $\forall x \leq x_0 \approx 1.282$ it holds that
$\Phi(x) \leq 0.1 $
So I obtain:
$\frac{\displaystyle C + 1 - \frac{3n}{4}}{\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{3n}{16}}} \leq -1,28$
inserting this $C$ from above and rearranging yields:
$\left\lceil \frac{ \displaystyle 1,645 \cdot \sqrt{n} + n}{\displaystyle2}  \right\rceil  \leq \frac{\displaystyle -1,28 \sqrt{3n}+3n}{\displaystyle4}$
if I understand the comment of @Wei correctly, I can make use of the freedom of choice for $n$ and demand(!) that it should furthermore hold that
$\frac{ \displaystyle 1,645 \cdot \sqrt{n} + n}{\displaystyle2} \leq \frac{\displaystyle -1,28 \sqrt{3n}+3n}{\displaystyle4} - 1$
and this implies the preceding inequality. Now we can solve this for $n$
However, if I read @stochasticboy's comment correctly, one should be aware that by doing so one will maybe choose an $n$ higher than what would actually be needed.
Is this correct?

As mentioned in another answer, the question is about deciding what value of $n$ you need. Since you're anyway using the normal approximation for the type-I error, we might as well use the same for the type-II. Under this approximation, if the alternate is true, then $Z := \frac{\sum X_i - 3n/4 }{\sqrt{3n/16}} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1),$ and we want to ensure that $n$ is so large that $\sum X_i \ge \lfloor n/2 + 0.8225\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ with probability at least $0.9$. Dealing with the floor is messy, but to make life easier, we can just demand that $\sum X_i \ge n/2 + 0.8225\sqrt{n}$. Now note that we reject if $$ \sum X_i  \ge n/2 + 0.8225\sqrt{n} \iff Z \ge -\sqrt{\frac{n}{3}} + \frac{4 \cdot 0.8225}{\sqrt{3}}.$$ Since $Z$ is standard Gaussian, we know that $P(Z \ge -1.29) \approx 0.9015\ge 0.9.$ So, as long as the rejection threshold for $Z$ is smaller than $-1.29,$ we will get power at least $0.9$. This tells us that $n$ should satisfy the inequality $$ -\sqrt{n/3} + \frac{4 \cdot 0.8225}{\sqrt{3}} \le  -1.29,$$ which holds for $n \ge \lceil 30.5...\rceil,$ i.e., if $n \ge 31.$
Finally, we need to ensure that $n$ is so large that the normal approximation we're making is not incorrect. Typically, this is said to "kick-in" around $n = 30,$ so it suffices to take $n = 31$.
There's at least two sources of error here: firstly, since we dropped the $\lfloor \rfloor$ in the threshold, it's possible that you can reduce $n$ slightly and still retain power (i.e., maybe $n = 30$ works). Secondly, the normal approximation is, of course, just an approximation. If you want more precision than that, then you can explicitly work with Clopper-Pearson intervals, but the calculations would have to be more numerical.




I think I got the right idea from your post and incorporated it into my original post / start of this thread - can you check this?



where does your critical value come from? Specifically the use of the floor function and the value of $0.8225$ Should this not be the same critical value I used in my original computation regarding the satisfaction of the significance level $\alpha=0.05$?

0.8225 is just 1.645/2. The floor come from the fact that $\lfloor x\rfloor \ge \lceil x-1\rceil,$ with the inequality actually being an equality unless $x$ is an integer (which would be rare due to the $0.8225\sqrt{n}$ term) - in any case, the size of the test is no worse than $0.05$ if you use the floor above as a threshold.

You still have one degree of freedom left to use: the value of $n$.

Yes, but I struggle with the computation (I will edit this in the OG post now)

Ok, I have thought it more through and edited the OG post. I think this is what you had in mind?

Just to give a precise answer using the binomial distribution rather than a normal approximation,

you want to reject $H_0$ of the number of heads strictly exceeds the smallest value (given $n$) which has a cumulative probability of at least $0.95$ assuming $p=\frac12$ to achieve the desired significance
and you want that value to have cumulative probability of no more than $0.10$ assuming $p=\frac34$ to achieve the desired power

so, using $R$ and its binomial quantile and CDF binomial functions, you can look at
n <- 1:50
crit <- qbinom(0.95, n, 1/2)
which(pbinom(crit, n, 3/4) <= 0.10)
# 33 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
crit[33]
# 21

so you need $n=33$ (in which case you reject the null hypothesis if you see more than $21$ heads) or $n \ge 35$ (but not $34$).
